# why isnt .length a method that requires ()

Tags: javascript, methods, member

In JavaScript why doesn't the keyword length require ()? It seems all the other functions such as splice(), shift() require parenthesis.

Comment: Because its a `property` and not a `method`

Comment: And it isn't a keyword in Javascript

Comment: @Clyde, "why isn't .length a method" - "because it is a property and not a method"? How does that answer the question?

Comment: @chiccodoro My understanding is OP is assuming length is a method that does not need parenteses and he is asking why. And I think I'm not the only one assuming this interpretation

Comment: @Pablo what makes you assume this? read the question's title.

Comment: @chiccodoro Rephrasing the question on the title: Why is .length a method that does not require ()? I may be wrong, but that's what I understand

Comment: @chiccodoro : from the question, I conclude that OP thinks that `length` is a method and wanted to know why is it not called with the `()`. I cant tell for sure why its a property. The only explanation that I have is because one can assign a value to `length` or the EcmaScript specification specified it to be a `property`

Comment: @Pablo - when rephrasing the question you omitted the "not"

Comment: @chiccodoro And what is more, in the body of the question OP says: "all the other functions..."

Comment: Its was designed to be a property http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2

Comment: @Pablo - obviously the OP is not very firm in the language and needs some clarification, and a comment like "Because it is not a method" will not be of any help to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length is not a method. It is a property. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

When calling properties you do not need parentheses. 
A property is something that an object "knows" about it self. An array or a string in javascript knows its length. A method is something that needs to be calculated.

Length could have been a method on javascript strings if javascript had really needed to count the letters each time you want the length.

When get a value from a property you can make an assumption that it is quicker to get its value than it would be getting a value from a method call. (Although this is not always the case)

Comment: From the question title: "why isn't length a method" - Your answer says the obvious that the OP already stated themselves.

Comment: Tried to add a simple explanation of the difference between properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! I did appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

We can only speculate why it was made a plain property and not a method.

However, the `.length` is a constant value for each string/array, it does not modify anything when being computed (it's not "executed" like a method), and it would not take any parameters anyway. Therefore it qualified well as an accessor property.

Also, assigning to `.length` allows us to control the size of the array (shrinking/expanding it). It's more convenient (or at least: idiomatic) to use the existing property as a setter than to introduce an extra `.setLength(…)` method.

Comment: That's the only answer that really answers the OP's question (except mine of course :-))

Answer (score 1):

length is a property, not a function. therefore it doesn't need brackets().

The length property is calculated and updated when the objects changes, while calling a function length() would calculate this value upon each single call.

Comment: again, this does not explain the why, the OP already states that length is not a function: "why isn't length a method"

Answer (score 1):

`splice` and `shift` are operations that calculate something based on the current state and/or their parameters. Furthermore they change the array. `length` in contrast is constant for a given array, no operation need to retrieve it. There is no need to make it a function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my comment

The JavaScript array `length` property returns the number of elements in an array.
It is always one greater than the largest index value of the array

One can if required( not advisable) change the `length` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

The EcmaScript language specification, designed the `length` to be a property.

[Read Here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2)